# Is WinPE-SRT not in the WAIK anymore?

Tags: windows-7, winpe, waik

I am trying to build a WindowsPE recovery disk.  I noticed that winpe-srt.cab is missing from my WAIK installation.  I do not see a \Recovery folder nor do I see a WinPE_OCs, I only see a WinPE_FPs.

Also as a bonus question is there a guide or tutorial on how to make your own programs for WinPE?  For example Dell has their own little Dell Recovery software.

Answer (score 0):

This package is only part of the OEM Kits (OPK). I found a [downloadlink on msfn](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/158123-opk-for-windows-8/?p=1051630) where an user created a tool to extract packsges from the WIM files into new CABs.